# How to write my virtual functions cleanly

Tags: c++, c++17

I am fairly new to c++ and learning how to write clean code.
I want to rewrite the function  manage() in derived1mngr and derived2mngr class below.
The code is common to both functions, only difference is the objecytype used to call the code.
I do not want to replicate the same code in derived1mngr and derived2mngr.
Any suggestions would help?
How can i group the code together in base class manage ?

```
class Base{
    public:
    virtual void handle(){
        cout<< "handle base";
        ....//do something
    }
    void fn1() {...}
    .....
    void fn10() {...}
};

 class D1: public Base{
    public:
    void handle(){
        Base::handle();
        cout<< "D1 handle";
        ....//do something
    }
};
class D2: public Base{
    public:
    void handle(){
        Base::handle();
        cout<< "D2 handle";
        ....//do something
    }
};

class basemngr {
    public:
        virtual void manage() {
        }
        void callA() {....};
        void callB() {...};
};

class derived1mngr: public basemgr{
    public:
      void manage() {
          D1 d1;
          d1.handle();
          d1.fn1();
          d1.fn2();
          if ( d1.fn3()) {
              callA(); 
          }
         if ( d1.fn4()) {
              callB(); 
          }
        }
};

class derived2mgr{
    public:
          void manage() {
              D2 d2;
              d2.handle();
              d2.fn1();
              d2.fn2();
              if ( d3.fn3()) {
                  callA(); 
             }
             if ( d2.fn4()) {
                  callB(); 
             }
        }
};

int main ()
{
     basemgr* d1m = new derived1mgr();
     d1m-> manage();
}
```

Comment: I don't get the point of derivedXmgrs, since every interface is implemented in basemgrs. Why not just use basemgrs and accept the base parameter. Is there any reason you need to let mgr class to instantiate the object?

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
class basemngr {
    public:
        virtual void manage() {
        }
        void manageImpl(Base& b) {
          b.handle();
          b.fn1();
          b.fn2();
          // ...
        }
        void callA() {....};
        void callB() {...};
};

class derived1mngr: public basemgr{
    public:
      void manage() {
          D1 d1;
          manageImpl(d1);
     }
};
```

Comment: Tadetnik b.handle() is a virtual call.

Comment: @newbie And...? In what way does this fact affect the proposed solution, in your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, inheritance with virtual functions is not for code reuse. Templates are.

This case screams for a template because as you point out the functions are the same except for the type used.

```
template <typename D, typename M>  
inline void manage(M& mngr) {
  D d;
  d.handle();
  d.fn1();
  d.fn2();
  if (d1.fn3()) {
    mngr.callA(); 
  }
  if (d.fn4()) {
    mngr.callB(); 
  }
}
```

This free function can then be called like this:

```
derived2mgr mngr;
manage<D2>(mngr);
```

Note that you can improve on this, by specifing the `D` type each class wants to use:

```
class MyMngr {
  public:
    using D = D3;
    /* ... */
};
```

Which would allow us to rewrite the function and remove the need to state which `D` type to use explicitly -> Less chance to make a mistake.

```
template <typename M>  
inline void manage(M& mngr) {
  typename M::D d;
  // ...
}
```